# Creating a word grabbing job in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I want to create a job using PHP which is able to loop through a dictionary and copies all words of it into my database. This is my only requirement.

[As I asked here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29454/dictionary-words-api), I was looking for some APIs which would do this job. But I did not find any good API, and it looks like nobody else did. So the only possibility would be creating a job which, for example, gets somehow all words of a site like dict.cc or something.

How could I start building such a job? What do I have to pay attention on? Do you have any input or ideas of conception for such a purpose?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: and the "specific" programming question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scribe the data by using PERL or curl scripts. In http://www.duden.de dictionary website, use the following simple idea

http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/**word**

you replace the the word "**word**" by your searching word. for eg if you want to get meaning for the word car, the url must be as follows

http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/**car**

Thus we have to find the target url and scribe the data. Perl Script is better than curl. I don't know script .. you just google it how to develop perl script to scribe data ..

Hope this information will usefull for u

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can create a kind of `dictionary` of the following format (*for e.g.*):

```
sauna, stoombad|Sauna
fitnessruimte|Fitnessroom
air-conditioning, airconditioning|Air Conditioning
wifi, wlan, internet, adsl, internettoegang|Internet
open haard|Open fire
tv|Television
sat, sat-tv|Satelite
afwasmachine|Vaatwasser
magnetron, combimagnetron|Microwave
oven, mini-oven|Oven
kluis|Safe
koelkast, koel-/vriescombinatie|Frige
koffiemachine|Coffemachine
diepvriezer|Freezer
```

than you should read `file` to `array`, `explode` it into `values` and `main word` for e.g.:

```
foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value) {
  list($values, $option) = explode('|', $value);
  $values = explode(',', $values);
  $dictionary[$key] = array('option' => trim($option), 'values' => $values);
}
```

And use the following method to retrieve the desired effect (*you can also use `array_walk()` and apply separate function to each item to do the same*):

```
foreach ($dictionary[$key]['values'] as $index => $value)
  $itemValues[$index] = '\b'.str_replace(array('/'), array('\/'), trim($value)).'\b'; // adding word boundary to each element and escaping slashes for regexp
```

And using array of read values compose a `RegExp pattern` to search for a particular set of words.

```
$pattern = '/'.implode('|', $itemValues).'/i'; // composing RegExpr pattern with case-insensitive option
```

Using this `pattern` you can `preg_match` any text. If any word exists in the text, for e.g. `air-conditioning` or `airconditioning`, `preg_match` will return `true` and you will know that `Air Conditioning`  (the word after `|` in your dictionary) is available in the text. You are doing such `preg_match` for each `dictionary` item against your text, thus you can collect word you listed.

You can omit using set of words and use word-per-row and test text more detailed (*for each single word*).

This technique is very good to use for extraction or **testing texts for presence** of set of words (*or one word in different variations or languages*) and **link** them **to** some **generalized** word or meaning.